# Как сравнить несколько атрибутов у элементов с одним классом используя jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В приведённом примере, изменения для div с классом wrap применяются только если, внести изменения в  input 3 Просьба помочь сделать так, чтобы изменения к div с классом wrap применялись если, заполнены все input с классом formWrap и если, они получили значение атрибута равное true

```js
$('.formWrap').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ''){
      $(this).attr('aria-invalid','true');
    }
    else if($(this).val() == ''){
      $(this).attr('aria-invalid','false');
    }
    $('.formWrap').each(function(){
      var frmWrapAttr = $(this).attr('aria-invalid');
      var frmStrng = 'true';
      if(frmWrapAttr == frmStrng){
        $('.wrap').css('background','#39f');
      }
      else if(frmWrapAttr != frmStrng){
        $('.wrap').css('background','#f39');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='formWrap' placeholder='input 1' aria-invalid='false' />

<input type='text' сlass='formWrap' placeholder='input 2' aria-invalid='false' />

<input type='text' class='formWrap' placeholder='input 3' aria-invalid='false' />

<div class='wrap'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй инпут вообще не реагировал, такое ощущение, что были буквы из другого алфавита, сделал копипаст третьего и заменил плейсхолдер и теперь всё хорошо.

```js
$('.formWrap').on('input', function(){        
    $('.formWrap').each(function(){
        // всякого рода валидация и установка атрибутов        
        $(this).attr('aria-invalid', $(this).val() === '');           
    });
        
    let invalidFormWrapCount = $('.formWrap[aria-invalid="true"]').length;    
    $('.wrap').css('background', invalidFormWrapCount === 0  ? '#39f' : '#f39');
});
```

```css
.wrap{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='formWrap' placeholder='input 1' aria-invalid='false' />
<input type='text' class='formWrap' placeholder='input 2' aria-invalid='false' />
<input type='text' class='formWrap' placeholder='input 3' aria-invalid='false' />

<div class='wrap'></div>
```